# C# - avoid null pointers in LINQ ToDictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I've got an object like this:

```
class Moose
{
   public int? DatabaseID;   // (null if not stored)
   public string Name;
}

List<moose> meese;
```

and I want to generate a dictionary that maps DatabaseID to Name for those meese that have a non-null DatabaseID.

The direct route doesn't work:

```
Dictionary<int, string> mapIdToName = meese.Where(moose => moose.DatabaseID != null).ToDictionary(moose => moose.DatabaseID, moose => moose.Name);
```

I get

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int?, string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>'
```

If I was creating a list, I could do this:

```
List<int> databaseIDs = meese.Select(moose => moose.DatabaseID).OfType<int>();
```

But I can't find anything similar for ToDictionary.

Right now I'm just doing it manually:

```
Dictionary<int, string> mapIdToName = new Dictionary<int, string>();
foreach (var moose in meese)
{
   if (moose.DatabaseID != null)
      mapIdToName[moose.DatabaseID] = moose.Name;
}
```

Is there a clever Linq way to do this?

EDIT

I've got

```
#nullable enable
```

so doing this

```
Dictionary<int, string> mapIdToName = meese.Where(moose => moose.DatabaseID.HasValue).ToDictionary(moose => moose.DatabaseID.Value, moose => moose.Name);
```

does not produce an error but does produce the warning "Nullable value type may be null"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
var map = meese.Where(moose => moose.DatabaseID.HasValue).ToDictionary(moose => moose.DatabaseID!.Value, moose => moose.Name);
```

Note the `!` after `DatabaseID`, the `dammit operator` or `null forgiving operator` where you basically tell the compiler I know for a FACT this isn't `null` so pipe down.

Comment: Oh I hate the dammit operator (it tastes like losing) but this might be a case where it's necessary

Comment: Or `GetValueOrDefault`

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it with the first try. When mapping a Nullable type to its base type, you need to remember to unbox the value. It should be something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> mapIdToName = meese.Where(moose => moose.DatabaseID.HasValue).ToDictionary(moose => moose.DatabaseID.Value, moose => moose.Name);
```

Comment: That does get closer, I didn't realize at first that having NRT enabled would change things so I edited my original post.  The compiler does accept this, and the humans reading it would agree it's correct, but the compiler is still nervous (gives me a warning) that moose.DatabaseID.Value might be null

Comment: I think the underlying problem is that Where() returns the same type it's given, so even after the Where() that us humans realize filters out the null values, the type is still Dictionary<int?, string>

Comment: just specify the ID.Value, like ` meese.Where(a=>a.DatabaseID.HasValue).ToDictionary(a=>a.DatabaseID.Value, b=>b.Name)`

Comment: Yup, that's what greenjaed proposed - it's better in that I don't get a compile-time error, but I still get a warning (I've updated my post to include that info)